# Exclude data from .map in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this .map function that returns all the employers that are enabled.

```
 ::Employer.enabled.ordered.map do |e|
```

I need to filter out employers that == "some text"

I tried this but it isn't giving me the result I'm looking for:

```
::Employer.enabled.ordered.map do {|e| e.name == "some text" ? nil : [e] }.compact
```

I'm new to Ruby and not great at syntax, what am I missing?

Comment: I think you want to read something off `e`, right? Like `name`? Rather than comparing an ActiveRecord instance to a string?

Comment: You're right. e.id. Changed that, still nothing.

Comment: How can an `Employer` equal a string like `"some text"`? Are employers just names and do you want to find a specific employer with that name? Or is an employer actually a more complex model and only an attribute of an employer hast that text?

Comment: Seems like a better use case for `where` e.g. `::Employer.enabled.ordered.where.not(name: "some text")` but this assumes `enabled` and `ordered` are scopes (which they should be anyway)

Comment: Updated code above. Still feel like the syntax is wrong.

Comment: @engineersmnky: If I did use the .where, how do I update e with this filtered list?

Comment: How do I return the Employee object? generally, I use a stand-in [like e in this case, to perform transforms on and return that]

Comment: Have you actually tried what I posted? Right now either: A) your post is unclear as to what your desire is?; B) you are not 100% clear on how Rails (ActiveRecord) works. In the case of A I would recommend updating your question to be more clear; in the case of B I would recommend doing some research outside of SO to better understand rails and the rails ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `select` [method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-select) available in ruby

```
a = [:foo, 'bar', 2, :bam]
a1 = a.select {|element| element.to_s.start_with?('b') }
a1 # => ["bar", :bam]
```

For your specific use case (Only keep items where `e` does not equal `some text`):

```
::Employer.enabled.ordered.select do {|e| e.name != "some text" }
```

Other options would be `select!`, `reject!` or `reject`. Each of them comes with a different behavior, but they are used in order to `filter`.

Comment: This selects what I do need. I only need to exclude one piece of text and keep everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has a nice Enumerable method for this scenario: `reject`.

```rb
::Employer.enabled.ordered.reject { |e| e.name == "unwanted-name" }
```